# How could I correct this macro?

Tags: c, macros

I wrote this for my homework:

```
#define SUMARRAY(array, size) ({   \
    int sum = 0;                   \
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) \
    {                              \
        sum += array[i];           \
    }                              \
    sum;                           \
})
```

The warning is:

> ISO C forbids braced-groups within expression

Edit:
Compiler:

> gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
> ISO C11

The assignment is:

> Write a program that defines and uses macro SUMARRAY to sum the values in a numeric array. The macro should receive the array and the number of elements in the array as arguments.

Comment: How do you use that macro? What compiler do you use? What standard setting?

Comment: In standard C blocks enclosed in `{}` are not considered as expressions and do not evaluate to a value. That is some GCC extension. What is it you are trying to do? You could just add a third parameter that is supposed to hold the result of your loop.

Comment: Is your homework to write macros? If not, make it a normal function instead.

Comment: While it is generally better to avoid compiler extensions when they're not needed, I do want to mention `__extension__`, which is how you would suppress the diagnostic message.

Comment: You wrote this for your homework, but what was the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a macro for this.

You use a gcc extension to create an expression from a statement, which your compiler refuses under strict ISO C conformance option (`-std=c90` or similar), there is no simple solution to write this macro is a conformant way.

Note these extra problems with this macro:

- the macro arguments are not parenthesized in the expansion, so you may experience precedence problems if you pass expressions.
- the macro defines new variables `i` and `sum`... This will pose a problem if you already have variables with these names where you instantiate the macro, especially if you pass `sum` or `i` as a macro argument.
- the macro assumes `array` has integer contents

Here is a safer way to write this macro:

```
#define SUMARRAY(array, size) ({              \
    int sum__ = 0;                            \
    size_t size__ = (size);                   \
    typeof(*(array)) *array__ = (array);      \
    for (size_t i__ = 0; i__ < size__; i__++) \
        sum__ += array__[i__];                \
    sum__;                                    \
})
```

I would recommend you write a function instead:

```
static inline int sumarray(const int *array, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum;
}
```

If you really need to use a macro, write it as a simple wrapper:

```
#define SUMARRAY(array, size)  sumarray(array, size)
```

Comment: If the homework actually was to write this as a Macro, as a teacher, I would fail the student writing a wrapper, tbh... maybe not if they would write it as a specifically inline function.

Comment: @Cediwelli: you have a good point: in an interview, it is important to give the expected answer and then explain why it is flawed and how to improve it, assuming the teacher will deal with criticism gracefully. A famous urban legend illustrates this dilemma: the [Barometer question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question).

Comment: @chqrlie Not sure I agree with "important to give the expected answer", or at least, it can depend on whether you care more about getting the highest grade, or being true to yourself.  And here on SO we regularly have questions where it's purely impossible to give the "expected answer", at least not without reading the examiner's mind.  Case in point: "What is the output of `int i = 5; printf("%d\n", i++ + i++);`?"  (Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244362).)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the possibility of conflicts with variables of the same name. The conflict can occur when the macro is expanded. At the end of the day, i used a wrapper.